# XMLHttpRequest - execute operation on webservice

Tags: javascript, soap

I am able to connect to the webservice. That service has a number of operations that can be executed and return a result. One is called helloWorld. I would like to perform that operation. Right now I specify the web service file, but i need to further specify the method in the file to be executed. Here is what I have:

```
function soapReq() {
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            // Get the data from the server's response
            console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'http://theWebServiceNameThatICannotGiveOut', true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Can I add the operation to be performed onto the end of the url or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should find something on the server, or find the page that has the `hello world` operation. Then you can make a request to that page (see example below), and you don't need it to be a `POST` request, just use `GET`.

Example:

```
// something like this:
ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'http://site.xxx/helloWorld.php', true);
// or this
ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'http://site.xxx/helloWorld.php?somevar=somevalue', true);
// or also this
ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'http://site.xxx/somepage.php?op=helloWorld', true);
```

But ***I can't help you more than this if you can't provide the site you're trying to make the request to.*** You should ask someone that works on it or search on the site itself.